# Dalli caching doesn't work rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, memcached, dalli

Am trying to use Rails.cache.read and Rails.cache.write helpers during my rspec scenario but it doesn't work. Am using dalli_store for cache store.
I wrote

```
ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
```

in any random test scenario and then run only this rspec. And when I jump to the next line to the breakpoint and try to write in console

```
Rails.cache.write("f", "b") => true
Rails.cache.read("f") => nil
```

When I do the same thing in console running in dev env -  I've got all expected results. It stores the values in cache and returns it

Answer (score 0):

Is Dalli configured

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

in your config/environments/test.rb environment? I believe it defaults to `:null_store`, which means your test environment will not have caching enabled. Also, be sure to return `ActionController::Base.perform_caching` back to its original state after your spec runs.

Comment: config.cache_store is sets to :dalli_store value. But it doesn't help. Am thinking maybe just Rails.cache.* helpers are doesn't work. Cause if I try to initialize dalli staff like this:   CACHE = Dalli::Client.new(’127.0.0.1′, { :namespace => “my_project”, :expires_in => 3600, :socket_timeout => 3, :compress => true })   - I can set and get data via: CACHE.set and CACHE.get.

Comment: Is `config.cache_store` set specifically in the config/environments/ **test.rb** file?

Comment: yes. I have 2 options for caching in test.rb file. config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store